# Embeding a website into your own website using your own css?

Tags: html, css, web-hosting

I use a website that recently changed its layout, which I (and a lot of other people) extremely dislike. I checked over the changes, and I believe that most of the changes involve a simple css change.

I own a domain that I would like to display the contents of this website, but with my own css, however I am unfamiliar with the web. I am open to all solutions that would do this (embedding, reflecting, etc.) I would like to do this without paying money.

*Note: the reason I am avoiding using a userstyle is because I would like to be able to access this website on any computer, anywhere, anytime, and let others do the same.

The website in question is http://www.scarsdaleschools.org/, and I would like it to look like [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314173925/http://scarsdaleschools.org/site/default.aspx?PageID=1).

I know there might be some conflicts with the using the old css on the current website, it is okay as long as it is usable.

I will give an additional 50 point bounty if the solution does not involve me hosting my own website.

Clarification: I am not looking to create a mirror for the website, I would like a client to access scarsdaleschools.org directly, only replace all css documents with my own css, thus all content is accessed directly from scarsdaleschools.org.

EDIT: This was put on hold as too broad. I am looking for a method by which I can accomplish what I am trying to do.

According to the help center:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Chances are, there is probably only one way (or a small few ways) that can answer my question. Regardless, my question does not require a few paragraphs, but just a simple name of a technique (and hopefully a small explanation of how I would use this technique).

Comment: You might be able to claim fair use, but I'd doubt it. You'd be taking a big risk with copyright.

Comment: Check out https://userstyles.org/ -- it may be able to help without hosting your own website.

Comment: @Quentin is right that this is a real can of worms if you try to host. However, something that might easily solve your problem would be to write a userscript/userstyle and just use that (and distribute that to the other people). Worth looking into.

Comment: The question explicitly rejects user styles.

Comment: Read their terms: 'You may not “mirror” any Content or the Solution on any other server.' is explicitly defined.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Jesse Kernaghan okay, thanks. I guess I will have to do it without mirroring then!

Comment: I have edited the OP, can this please be reopened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you don't mind having to put some *insane* amounts of `!important` in your CSS for it, the `iframe` tag is actually powerful enough to do it (doesn't even need the proposed-then-[cancelled](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/331) `seamless` attribute).

I'd still suggest using something like [a portable browser](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) on a flashdrive/CD, and having your userstyles installed on that, instead, as it's a little less red-flag-inducing (your site may be flagged as a potential attack site w/ the iframe trick). Added bonuses, it dodges corpsec spyware and update restrictions, and has all your bookmarks/addons.

But simply `iframe`ing the website from your own with your stylesheet (loaded with `!important`s) will suffice, so long as you can get around any framekiller they use (if any).

Comment: My understanding is that the `seamless` attribute only integrates the website as part of your own website (this is not necessary for me.) If so, how would I use the `iframe` tag to display the website but replace the css file with my own?

Comment: Actually, my bad entirely. `Seamless` is unnecessary. Your only concern then is whether or not you need to dodge a "framekiller"

Comment: I am able to display the site within a frame. I just need to know how to override the site css with my css within the frame.

Comment: _Well if you don't mind having to put some **insane** amounts of `!important` in your CSS for it_...

Comment: I don't mind. How would I use `!important` ?

Comment: `property: value !important;` [The Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules). It lets you subvert the cascade. If you tag every single one of your properties with it, only their ones using it will win. You also might be able to beat it by tossing a `#id` selector in front of the selectors to target the `iframe` itself. Might actually work better, too. Also, protip, always check the Google (searching for `css important` nets at least 4 good explanations as the first 4 results, likely more).

Comment: Ah, I see. So !important lets me override the iframe css. What does it mean to toss an #id selector in front of the selectors to target the iframe?

Comment: `<iframe id='wrapperframe' />` is targettable by `#wrapperframe`, but I'm not sure if you can propagate your style adjustments into it that way. Would have to test. If you *can*, it would raise the specificity level of all of your selectors to be higher than those internal to the frame, meaning you won't need `!important`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107790/discussion-between-mark-wright-and-abluejelly).